# Python Syntax Error in Except Suite

Tags: python, except

I am getting a syntax error in a try suite on a variable created within the try suite. Is it not correct to call a variable in the except suite that was created in the try suite? This is the only reason I could think of that there would be a syntax error for that variable.

```
try:
 file_name = input('Enter the encrypted file: ')
 encryptionKey = open(input('Enter the file name for theencryptionkey: '),'r')
 anEncryptedLine = open(file_name)
 decrypted_file = open(decrypted_file.txt,'a+')
 decrypted_str = ''
 for i in decrypted_file:
    decrptyed_line =substitutionDecrypt(i)
    print(decrypted_line, file=decrypted_file.txt)

except IOError:
 print('The file 'file_name'doesn\'nt exist')
```

The syntax error is appearing on the variable 'file_name' in the last line

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Python does not support this kind syntax, you should use:

```
try:
    file_name = input('Enter the encrypted file: ')
    encryptionKey = open(input('Enter the file name for theencryptionkey: '),'r')
    anEncryptedLine = open(file_name)
    decrypted_file = open(decrypted_file.txt,'a+')
    decrypted_str = ''
    for i in decrypted_file:
       decrptyed_line =substitutionDecrypt(i)
       print(decrypted_line, file=decrypted_file.txt)
except IOError:
    print('The file \'%s\'doesn\'nt exist' % file_name)
    # or print('The file \'{}\'doesn\'nt exist'.format(file_name))
```

For Python 3.6:

```
print(f'The file \'{file_name}\'doesn\'nt exist')
```

Comment: I am certain I have used that exact print syntax in Python 3.6. Its my main way to print.

Comment: @juggy_crisp: It's only valid with string literals. Non-literal expressions need to be composed into the string properly, either with formatting/interpolation or with concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use string concatenation in:

```
print("The file" + " " + file_name + " " + "doesn\'t exist")
```